# Javascript show 5 items each time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to show only 5 items in a row, the next 5 items will stay invisble and the be visible after some seconds then the first items will be invisble, how can i acchieve that with my for loops?

```
var array = [" England", " USA", " Africa", " Spain", " Italy", " Norway", " Sweden", "   Denmark", " Island", " Russia"];
var maxRows = 5;
var row = array.length/maxRows;
var rows = row.toFixed();
var counter = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++){

   for( var k = 0; k < 5; k++){
     $("#output").append(array[k]);
}
counter += 5;
$("#output").append(counter);

}
```

Comment: [window.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) is useful for setting up animations like this.  Basically, use your for loop to divide the array and use setTimeout to tell the browser how to change the display in the future.  Important: There is no pause or wait function in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive function that sets a timeout to itself:

```
function showCountries(start) {
    for (var i = start; i < start + 5; i++){
        if(i > array.length) return;

        $("#output").append(array[k]);
    }
    counter += 5;
    $("#output").append(counter);

    // call the function again after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        showCountries(start + 5);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Good but it will need a way to stop when it runs out of input.

Comment: @Paul : i assume `if(i > array.length) return;` will take care of that!!  :)

Comment: Yeah that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try  `setInterval()`

`

```
var maxRows = 5;
var row = array.length/maxRows;
var rows = row.toFixed();
var counter = 0;
var i=0;
var temp=5;
setInterval(function(){
    $("#output").html('');
    for ( i = i; i < array.length; i++){    
       $("#output").append(array[i]);
        if(i==temp){
            temp=temp+5; // if (temp => array.length ) {temp=5;} //you can set temp =5;
            break;
        }    
    }    
},2000);
```

`

Comment: @Peter -  Above code display records in every 2 Seconds -

Comment: @Peter - you can set value for `temp=5` when `temp` is greater then  `array.length`. - see the code is updated